# Why do I get `undefined` when using `document.getElementsByClassName(...).value`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why do I get `undefined` as result of `console.log(tes_val)`? How can I fix it?

```js
var tes = document.getElementsByClassName('a_b_1');
var tes_val = tes.value;
console.log(tes_val);
```

```html
<input type="hidden" class="a_b_1" name="c_d_1" value="1|2|3">
```

Thank you.

Comment: Because `tes` is a collection. Use `var tes_val = tes[0].value;`.

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns a collection like an array. If there is only one element with that class name you can use tes[0].value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), so in order to access first found element in this collection you need to use `[0]` index:

```
var tes_val = tes[0].value;
```

However, this is clumsy way to use API. If you are only interested in the first element with class `a_b_1` use [Document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method:

```
var tes = document.querySelector('.a_b_1');
var tes_val = tes.value;
console.log(tes_val);
```

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByClassName(...)` returns a list of elements. Note the plural `s` in the name of the method! Use `getElementsByClassName(...)[0]` to access the first element in the list.

```js
var tes = document.getElementsByClassName('a_b_1')[0]
var tes_val = tes.value
console.log(tes_val) //=> "1|2|3"
```

```html
<input type="hidden" class="a_b_1" name="c_d_1" value="1|2|3">
```

Answer (score 0):

[**document.getElementsByClassName**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) array-like object of all child elements.

So you have to select the specific element by passing the index

```
var tes = document.getElementsByClassName('a_b_1');
var tes_val = tes[0].value;
console.log(tes_val);
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/62p9v4c3/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var tes = $('.a_b_1');
var tes_val = tes.val();
console.log(tes_val);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" class="a_b_1" name="c_d_1" value="1|2|3">
```

Use `.val()` for jquery